# How can Pandas DataFrames appear identical but fail equals()?

Tags: python, pandas

To confirm that I understand what Pandas `df.groupby()` and `df.reset_index()` do, I attempted to do a round-trip from a dataframe to a grouped version of the same data and back. After the round-trip the columns and rows had to be sorted again, because `groupby()` affects row order and `reset_index()` affects column order, but after two quick maneuvers to put the columns and index back in order, the dataframes look identical:

- Same list of column names.
- Same dtypes for every column.
- Corresponding index values are strictly equal.
- Corresponding data values are strictly equal.

Yet, after all of these checks succeed, `df1.equals(df5)` returns the astounding value `False`.

What difference between these dataframes is `equals()` uncovering that I have not yet figured out how to check for myself?

Test code:

```
csv_text = """\
Title,Year,Director
North by Northwest,1959,Alfred Hitchcock
Notorious,1946,Alfred Hitchcock
The Philadelphia Story,1940,George Cukor
To Catch a Thief,1955,Alfred Hitchcock
His Girl Friday,1940,Howard Hawks
"""

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df1.columns = map(str.lower, df1.columns)
print(df1)

df2 = df1.groupby(['director', df1.index]).first()
df3 = df2.reset_index('director')
df4 = df3[['title', 'year', 'director']]
df5 = df4.sort_index()
print(df5)

print()
print(repr(df1.columns))
print(repr(df5.columns))
print()
print(df1.dtypes)
print(df5.dtypes)
print()
print(df1 == df5)
print()
print(df1.index == df5.index)
print()
print(df1.equals(df5))
```

The output that I receive when I run the script is:

```
                    title  year          director
0      North by Northwest  1959  Alfred Hitchcock
1               Notorious  1946  Alfred Hitchcock
2  The Philadelphia Story  1940      George Cukor
3        To Catch a Thief  1955  Alfred Hitchcock
4         His Girl Friday  1940      Howard Hawks
                    title  year          director
0      North by Northwest  1959  Alfred Hitchcock
1               Notorious  1946  Alfred Hitchcock
2  The Philadelphia Story  1940      George Cukor
3        To Catch a Thief  1955  Alfred Hitchcock
4         His Girl Friday  1940      Howard Hawks

Index(['title', 'year', 'director'], dtype='object')
Index(['title', 'year', 'director'], dtype='object')

title       object
year         int64
director    object
dtype: object
title       object
year         int64
director    object
dtype: object

  title  year director
0  True  True     True
1  True  True     True
2  True  True     True
3  True  True     True
4  True  True     True

[ True  True  True  True  True]

False
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Another way to check is to use `pandas.util.testing.assert_frame_equal`. That might give you a report about what Pandas thinks is different.

Comment: Good idea! Just tried it. It raises no exception if its arguments are `assert_frame_equal(df1, df5)` as the last line in the above script. So it seems to think they are equal even though `.equals()` does not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feels like a bug to me, but could be simply that I'm misunderstanding something.  The blocks are listed in a different order:

```
>>> df1._data
BlockManager
Items: Index(['title', 'year', 'director'], dtype='object')
Axis 1: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
IntBlock: slice(1, 2, 1), 1 x 5, dtype: int64
ObjectBlock: slice(0, 4, 2), 2 x 5, dtype: object
>>> df5._data
BlockManager
Items: Index(['title', 'year', 'director'], dtype='object')
Axis 1: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
ObjectBlock: slice(0, 4, 2), 2 x 5, dtype: object
IntBlock: slice(1, 2, 1), 1 x 5, dtype: int64
```

In `core/internals.py`, we have the `BlockManager` method

```
def equals(self, other):
    self_axes, other_axes = self.axes, other.axes
    if len(self_axes) != len(other_axes):
        return False
    if not all (ax1.equals(ax2) for ax1, ax2 in zip(self_axes, other_axes)):
        return False
    self._consolidate_inplace()
    other._consolidate_inplace()
    return all(block.equals(oblock) for block, oblock in
               zip(self.blocks, other.blocks))
```

and that last `all` assumes that the blocks in `self` and `other` correspond.  But if we add some `print` calls before it, we see:

```
>>> df1.equals(df5)
blocks self: (IntBlock: slice(1, 2, 1), 1 x 5, dtype: int64, ObjectBlock: slice(0, 4, 2), 2 x 5, dtype: object)
blocks other: (ObjectBlock: slice(0, 4, 2), 2 x 5, dtype: object, IntBlock: slice(1, 2, 1), 1 x 5, dtype: int64)
False
```

and so we're comparing the wrong things.  The reason I'm not sure whether or not this is a bug is because I'm not sure whether `equals` is *meant* to be this finicky or not.  If so, I think there's a doc bug, at least, because `equals` should then shout that it's not meant to be used for what you might think it would be from the name and the docstring.

Comment: Can you make an issue for this?

Comment: was originally reported here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9330; the block ordering is an impl detail atm. there are some options at he end of the issue in order to make this consistent.

Comment: Thank you, all! I have appended this sample code to the issue to warn them that this is not HDF-specific but can strike anyone.